# C# application on a shared drive / site / what else?

Tags: c#, shared, sql-server-2014-express

**Hello all,**

I just created a C# application that connects to a server database, it can insert, update, search, delete the files from the database, more than this I can view all the files in a listview.
I have encountered the following problems:

**1)** I don't want the application to be instaled on every PC from work, I want it to be instaled on a shared drive and every PC can open the application from a folder inside that drive (I don't want them to connect remoutly to my PC). I heard that there would be an another solution, that I can put my app into a Site (I have no idea how.. never did that before);

**2)** I have no idea how many PC can use the application at the same time ( but somehow I don't think that should be a problem because I tried inserting into the database through SQL manager at the same time with a mate and there were no problems) but if I put the application to be shared from the same drive it could cause problems;

**3** I would love some tips how to make my application work nicer ( it started getting laggy after a few show/hide text boxes and labels..

Well the most important for me would be point (1), I have no idea how can I do this, I am sure that it is possible somehow, I accepted doing this C# app without knowing like anything but now it makes me curious like hell!
Thank you in advance! (sorry for bad english)

Image:
[my first C# applicatipon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpmyO.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean a "shared" drive? How can it be shared without having other computers connect to your computer? This is probably a better question for SuperUser, not SO. We can't help you make your application "work nicer" if we can't see what is working wrong. This is probably better broken out into individual questions.

Comment: We have a head Server with many drives on it and we can acces it each invidually, like your local disk D, but it is not local, I could copy the app there

Comment: but you are right "In computing, a shared resource, or network share, is a computer resource made available from one host to other hosts on a computer network" we are all connected to that shared network

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d) so the users can download and execute your app.

From the site:

> You can publish a ClickOnce application in three different ways: from
>   a Web page, from a network file share, or from media such as a CD-ROM.
>   A ClickOnce application can be installed on an end user's computer and
>   run locally even when the computer is offline, or it can be run in an
>   online-only mode without permanently installing anything on the end
>   user's computer.

Either that or convert to windows forms application to a web based application using ASP.Net.

Comment: *"I don't want the application to be instaled on every PC from work"* Not sure ClickOnce meets that requirement.

Comment: @RonBeyer well, one of ClickOnce's strategies is to  **Install or Run From Web** which just makes a temoporary install and then deletes the applciation after the user closes it.

Comment: ClickOnce it is not a bad solution thinking that even if you don't have to install the application you need to install the Net Framework, ClickOnce can handle that as far as I know, and you can update easily the app. I found a solution by debuging in a sort of way a copying all the dependencies but still, you need the framework..